# Problems again with child processes in Java

Tags: java, synchronization, processbuilder

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.
I am trying to run something like `ps aux | grep whatevah` through Java's class `ProcessBuilder`. I create two child processes and I make them communicate synchronously, but for some reason, I can not see anything in the terminal.

This is the code:

```
try {
    // What comes out of process1 is our inputStream
    Process process1   = new ProcessBuilder("ps", "aux").start();
    InputStream is1    = process1.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is1));

    // What goes into process2 is our outputStream
    Process process2  = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "gedit").start();
    OutputStream os   = process2.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

    // Send the output of process1 to the input of process2
    String p1Output  = null;
    while ((p1Output = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        bw.write(p1Output);
        System.out.println(p1Output);
    }
    // Synchronization
    int finish = process2.waitFor();
    System.out.println(finish);

    // What comes out of process2 is our inputStream            
    InputStream is2    = process2.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is2));

    String combOutput  = null;
    while ((combOutput = br2.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(combOutput);

    os.close();
    is1.close();
    is2.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Command execution error: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("General error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

(The `System.out.println(p1Output);` is just for me to check, the print that has to work is the last one, printing the result of `ps aux | grep whatevah`.)

I've tried several things, the less silly include:

- If I comment everything regarding process2, I get the result of `ps aux` printed on the terminal
- If I run the program as is, it prints nothing to the terminal.
- If I uncomment the `waitFor` call, only `ps aux` gets printed.
- If change the commands to, for example, `ls -al` and `ls -al`, then both get printed.
- I tried changing `"aux"` for `"aux |"` but still nothing is printed.
- Closed the buffers, also nothing

etc.

Any help will be sorely appreciated.
Cheers!

## EDIT

Minutes after accepting Ryan's amazing answer I made my last try to make this code work. And I succeeded! I changed:

```
while ((p1Output = br1.readLine()) != null) {
    bw.write(p1Output);
    System.out.println(p1Output);
}
```

for:

```
while ((p1Output = br1.readLine()) != null) {
    bw.write(p1Output + "\n");
    System.out.println(p1Output);
}

bw.close();
```

and it works! I remember closing the buffer before, so I don't know what went wrong. Turns out you should not stay awake until late trying to make a piece of code work XD.

Ryan's answer down here is still amazing, though.

Comment: probably because you need separate threads to process the input and output of a process.  Relevant article [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html).  most likely the first loop is blocking because you are not consuming the grep output in a timely manner.

Comment: @jtahlborn Sorry, what do you mean when you say that "you need separate threads to process the input and output"? Also, the article you link is for `Runtime`... could it apply to PB too?

Comment: the article explains why the threads are necessary.  Runtime.exec is just a shortcut for ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the advice in the comments, the important thing to note is the necessity to use threads to process input/output for a process in order to achieve what you want.

I've used the link posted by jtahlborn and adapted this solution that you might be able to use.

I created a simple example that will list files in a directory and grep through the output.
This example simulates the command `ls -1 | grep some` from a directory called `test` with three files `somefile.txt` `someotherfile.txt` and `this_other_file.csv`

**EDIT:** The original solution didn't really fully use the "pipe" methodology, as it was waiting fully for p1 to finish before starting p2. Rather, it should start them both, and then the output of the first should be piped to the second. I've updated the solution with a class that accomplishes this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // construct a process
            ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-1");
            // set working directory
            pb1.directory(new File("test"));

            // start process
            final Process process1 = pb1.start();

            // get input/error streams
            final InputStream p1InStream = process1.getInputStream();
            final InputStream p1ErrStream = process1.getErrorStream();

            // handle error stream
            Thread t1Err = new InputReaderThread(p1ErrStream, "Process 1 Err");
            t1Err.start();

            // this will print out the data from process 1 (for illustration purposes)
            // and redirect it to process 2
            Process process2  = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "some").start();

            // process 2 streams
            final InputStream p2InStream = process2.getInputStream();
            final InputStream p2ErrStream = process2.getErrorStream();
            final OutputStream p2OutStream = process2.getOutputStream();

            // do the same as process 1 for process 2...
            Thread t2In = new InputReaderThread(p2InStream, "Process 2 Out");
            t2In.start();
            Thread t2Err = new InputReaderThread(p2ErrStream, "Process 2 Err");
            t2Err.start();

            // create a new thread with our pipe class
            // pass in the input stream of p1, the output stream of p2, and the name of the input stream
            new Thread(new PipeClass(p1InStream, p2OutStream, "Process 1 Out")).start();

            // wait for p2 to finish
            process2.waitFor();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Command execution error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("General error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is a class that will be used to simulate a process pipe. It uses some loops to copy bytes around, and could be more efficient, depending on your needs, but for the illustration, it should work.

```
// this class simulates a pipe between two processes
public class PipeClass implements Runnable {
    // the input stream
    InputStream is;
    // the output stream
    OutputStream os;
    // the name associated with the input stream (for printing purposes only...)
    String isName;

    // constructor
    public PipeClass(InputStream is, OutputStream os, String isName) {
        this.is = is;
        this.os = os;
        this.isName = isName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // use a byte array output stream so we can clone the data and use it multiple times
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // read the data into the output stream (it has to fit in memory for this to work...)
            byte[] buffer = new byte[512]; // Adjust if you want
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            // clone it so we can print it out
            InputStream clonedIs1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(clonedIs1);

            // print the info
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(this.isName + " >> " + sc.nextLine());
            }

            // clone again to redirect to the output of the other process
            InputStream clonedIs2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            buffer = new byte[512]; // Adjust if you want
            while ((bytesRead = clonedIs2.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                // write it out to the output stream
                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                // close so the process will finish
                is.close();
                os.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a class that was created for handling process output, adapted from [this reference](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html)

```
// Thread reader class adapted from
// http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html
public class InputReaderThread extends Thread {
    // input stream
    InputStream is;
    // name
    String name;
    // is there data?
    boolean hasData = false;
    // data itself
    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();


    // constructor
    public InputReaderThread(InputStream is, String name) {
        this.is = is;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // set if there's data to read
    public synchronized void setHasData(boolean hasData) {
        this.hasData = hasData;
    }

    // data available?
    public boolean hasData() { return this.hasData; }

    // get the data
    public StringBuilder getData() {
        setHasData(false);  // clear flag
        StringBuilder returnData = this.data;
        this.data = new StringBuilder();

        return returnData;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // input reader
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(this.is);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(isr);
        // while data remains
        while ( sc.hasNextLine() ) {
            // print out and append to data
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(this.name + " >> " + line);
            this.data.append(line + "\n");
        }
        // flag there's data available
        setHasData(true);
    }
}
```

The produced output is:

```
Process 1 Out >> somefile.txt
Process 1 Out >> someotherfile.txt
Process 1 Out >> this_other_file.csv
Process 2 Out >> somefile.txt
Process 2 Out >> someotherfile.txt
```

To show that piping is really working, changing the command to `ps -a | grep usr` the output is:

```
Process 1 Out >>       PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID  TTY  UID    STIME COMMAND
Process 1 Out >> I   15016       1   15016      15016  con  400 13:45:59 /usr/bin/grep
Process 1 Out >>     15156       1   15156      15156  con  400 14:21:54 /usr/bin/ps
Process 1 Out >> I    9784       1    9784       9784  con  400 14:21:54 /usr/bin/grep
Process 2 Out >> I   15016       1   15016      15016  con  400 13:45:59 /usr/bin/grep
Process 2 Out >>     15156       1   15156      15156  con  400 14:21:54 /usr/bin/ps
Process 2 Out >> I    9784       1    9784       9784  con  400 14:21:54 /usr/bin/grep
```

Seeing the `grep` command in process 2's output shows that the piping is working, with the old solution I posted, this would be missing.

Note the handling of the error stream, which is always good practice, even if you don't plan to use it.

This is a quick and dirty solution that could benefit from some additional thread management techniques, but it should get you what you want.

Comment: the problem with this solution is you buffer the entire results of the first process before invoking the second.  instead, you want to stream the results from the first process into the second in one thread, while simultaneously reading the results from the second process in a second thread.

Comment: Yes, I had noted this would be a limitation, and worked to figure out a better way to handle it. I've updated my answer to reflect it. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Wow, I never imagined this could get so complex. Your answer and the article are mind blowing. I'm curious to know why is there so few information about this topic on the web and the best article is from the year 2000? Is people not doing this at all? Are there no use cases? Are they using a different approach?

Comment: Process mgmt and redirection is, in and of itself, very basic. It's simply a manipulation of file handles. Probably why you're not finding a whole lot of current information and solutions is because it's generally frowned upon if you can avoid it, due to the number of things you need to watch out for. It would probably be easier for you to let the shell do the work for you and simply use a script to pipe your commands, then you don't have to deal with it. The use of process communication is going to be very tailored to your specific needs, which is why you're not finding "general" solutions

Comment: PipeClass is not a pipe, it still reads all from one and writes to another.  it really is just a simple loop: read from inputstream(is), write to outputstream(os), repeat.

Comment: @mestevens - the reason there aren't any other articles (IMO) is because that article is very well known and pretty much sums everything up very well.

Comment: @jtahlborn understood, it's a simulator... just trying to convey the concept.